# Unable to Convert From ByteString When Reading a Kubernetes Secret Using kube-rs

Tags: kubernetes, rust

I'm attempting to read the contents of a Kubernetes Secret using `kube-rs`. The secret contains a key named "apiKey".

I seem to be able to pull the secret from the kube-apiserver (debug logging shows the correct contents of the secret) but I can't get to the value itself as it's returned as a `ByteString`.

I can't find a way to convert the `ByteString` to a `String`.

Could anyone kindly shed some light on this? My code is below, including my failed attempts and the related error messages.

```
use kube::{Client, api::{Api, ResourceExt, ListParams, PostParams}};
use k8s_openapi::api::core::v1::Secret;
use bytes::Bytes;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use k8s_openapi::ByteString;

async fn get_credentials_from_secret(secret_namespace: &String, secret_name: &String) -> Result<String, kube::Error> {

    let client = Client::try_default().await?;

    let secrets: Api<Secret> = Api::namespaced(client, secret_namespace);

    let secret: Secret = secrets.get(secret_name).await?;

    let secret_data: BTreeMap<String, ByteString>  = secret.data.unwrap();

    let api_key = &secret_data["apiKey"];
    println!("{:?}", api_key); // This prints 'ByteString([97, 112, 105, 107, 101, 121])'

//    let api_key_string: String = api_key.into(); // the trait `From<&ByteString>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
//    let api_key_slice = api_key.as_slice(); //  method not found in `&ByteString
//    let api_key_string: String = api_key.serialize(); // method not found in `&ByteString`
//    let api_key_string = String::from(api_key); // the trait `From<&ByteString>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`

    Ok("Secret data here ideally!".to_string())

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I saw that it had some serialization traits at https://docs.rs/k8s-openapi/0.13.1/src/k8s_openapi/lib.rs.html#482-506, so I resorted to using the `serde_json` crate which worked just fine.

```
use k8s_openapi::ByteString;
...
let some_byte_str = ByteString("foobar".as_bytes().to_vec());
serde_json::to_string(&some_byte_str).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @digitalfoo's answer but encountered `serde_json` putting an extra set of double quotes around the decoded string; e.g. in this case it was coming out like:

```
"\"foobar\""
```

So I ended up using something more-explicit (leveraging the OP's variable name):

```
use std::str::{ from_utf8, Utf8Error };
...

from_utf8(&api_key.0)?
```

Note that to propagate an error from `from_utf8`, you need to be equipped to handle `Utf8Error`; otherwise, you can just `unwrap`, `expect`, etc. Error propagation does allow more control for things like returning proper HTTP status codes.